# Why is my pc making a buzzing sound when it is running on an inverter

Tags: hardware-failure

Specifications:
Processor: Intel(R) Pentium(R) G2020
RAM: 4 Gb
Windows version: Windows 10 pro 2004 x64 bit
This is my problem that when my pc is running on AC current of my house is works perfectly fine but when it is running on home inverter is makes some buzzing sound just like a bee.
This only started after I upgraded from windows 8.1 to windows 10 and I don't know what to do.

Comment: Can you clarify that its the speakers that are making the buzzing sound, not the inverter itself?  If thats the case its most likely a grounding issue - ensure all the peripherals are also plugged into the inverter and/or they all share a common ground.

Comment: also buzzing noise is indicative of unclean output, typically a square wave output from an inverter